# "SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/openvpn from name_bind access on the tcp_socket"

Tags: centos, selinux, openvpn

I am configuring an openvpn server on a new centos 6.5. But the main problem is that selinux is blocking openvpn to use the default port tcp 1194.
The following is the sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/openvpn from name_bind access on the tcp_socket .

***** Plugin bind_ports (92.2 confidence) suggerisce  ************************

Se you want to allow /usr/sbin/openvpn to bind to network port 7505
Quindi you need to modify the port type.
Fai
# semanage port -a -t TIPO_PORTA -p tcp 7505
dove TIPO_PORTA è una delle seguenti: openvpn_port_t, http_port_t.
```

I am sorry, as u see the sealert is translated in italian. Anyway should I follow the advice like this:

```
# semanage port -a -t vpn -p udp 1194
```

or there are other more clean way to open the openvpn default port ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually the best error message I've seen. It tells you exactly what's wrong and how to fix it. I don't see any kind of problem if you really want to allow openvpn use port 1194.

BTW, to make errors in english you can use `LANG=C` before the commands (not sure if you can with auth.log).